# XML Data to multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I've got the following problem: After adding data to an array, it only stores the last insert.

I get the following result from my Code with var_dump:

```
array(5) { ["Mount01"]=> string(12) "DebugLevel#0" ["Mount02"]=> string(12) "DebugLevel#0" ["Mount03"]=> string(12) "DebugLevel#0" ["Mount04"]=> string(12) "DebugLevel#0" ["Mount05"]=> string(12) "DebugLevel#0" }
```

So it only saves the last input that I do. But I want it like that:

```
array(X) { ["Mount01"]=> string(XX) "DebugLevel#0" ["Mount01"]=> string(XX) "Bla#5" ["Mount02"]=> string(XX) "DebugLevel#0" ["Mount02"]=> string(XX) "Bla#5" }
```

This is my XML Structure:

```
<Config>
  <Core>
    <Store>
      <Mount01>
                <DebugLevel>0</DebugLevel>
                <Bla>5</Bla>
      <Mount02>
                <DebugLevel>0</DebugLevel>
                <Bla>5</Bla>
```

This is my Code:

```
class Storage{
  public static function get_storage_data()
  {
    if(file_exists('/var/www/content/data/data.xml')) :
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('/var/www/content/data/data.xml');
        foreach ($xml->Core->Store as $mounts) {
          foreach ($mounts as $mount) {
            foreach ($mount->Children() as $value) {
              $store[$mount->getName()]=$value->getName()."#".$value;
            }
          }
        }
        var_dump($store);
    else:
        write_log(sprintf("data.xml not found"));
    endif;
  }
```

So, how can I achive my wanted Output? Also Code improvements are welcome.

Comment: An array can only have one key with any given name, so the simple answer to "how can I achieve my wanted output" is "you can't", sorry. You'll need to come up with a different format that doesn't try to give the same key two different values.

Comment: Alright, so the best approach here is to find a better format. so it should be able to do if I do something like $array['mount01'] = $data['bla#5', 'bla2#6']. So I can literally do array_push($data,'bla#5') and at the end of the inner loop an $array['mount01']=$data? I never heard that storing an array as a value is a bad approach? I know that you can use "Structs" in C, but since php dont have them its not that easy.

Comment: got it, thanks @IMSoP for your hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function get_storage_data(
{
    if(file_exists('/var/www/content/data/data.xml')) :
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('/var/www/content/data/data.xml');
        foreach ($xml->Core->Store as $mounts) {
          foreach ($mounts as $mount) {
            $data=[];
            foreach ($mount->Children() as $value) {
              array_push($data,[$value->getName()."#".$value]);
            }
            $store[$mount->getName()]=$data;
          }
        }
    else:
        write_log(sprintf("data.xml not found"));
    endif;
  }
```

Answer to my Problem.